# Angular Material Table: Detect what rows (items) are currently being displayed

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need some way to track what items (rows) in a Material Table are currently being displayed. According to the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable), `<mat-table>` is built on top of `<cdk-table>`, giving it a `viewChange` property. My understanding is that this `BehaviorSubject` fires anytime the set of rows being displayed changes. For instance, there might be 400 total rows, but due to pagination, only 20 are on the screen. When the user clicks to go to the next page, this should cause `viewChange` to emit. Does anyone know how to use this property? I tried the following code, but it only fires once, with the value `{ start: 0, end: 1.7976931348623157e+308 }`.

component.ts:

```ts
allTasks = new MatTableDataSource<Task>([]);

@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sorter: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.allTasks.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.allTasks.sort = this.sorter;
  this.table.viewChange.asObservable().subscribe(val => {
    console.log(`${val.start} - ${val.end}`);
  });
}
```

component.html:

```xml
<mat-table
  matSort
  [dataSource]="this.allTasks"
>
...
</mat-table>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way that you can get the rows displayed is using the subscribe of the paginator and use the pageIndex to get the data from the dataSource.

```ts
allTasks = new MatTableDataSource<Task>([]);

@ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sorter: MatSort;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.allTasks.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.allTasks.sort = this.sorter;

  this.allTasks.paginator.page.subscribe((pageEvent: PageEvent) => {
      const startIndex = pageEvent.pageIndex * pageEvent.pageSize;
      const endIndex = startIndex + pageEvent.pageSize;
      const itemsShowed = this.allTasks.filteredData.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
      console.log(itemsShowed);
  });

}
```

Comment: Might need to take sorting into consideration as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760665/how-to-get-the-data-which-is-shown-only-in-the-page-of-material-datatable-with-p#60597539

Answer (score 8):

While Daniel solution works perfectly, I found something simpler.

```ts
this.allTasks.connect().value
```

will give you the rows displayed on the screen for the current page.

If you want all the filtered row (that might be displayed on several pages), you can also use:

```ts
this.allTasks.filteredData
```

Comment: This possibly creates a new subscription to the datasource each time it is called - so needs to be unsubscribed after use?

Comment: I don't think it does, the 'connect()' method returns a "BehaviorSubject", it would create a subscription if you would subscribe to it, but here we are taking the value directly using ".value".

So no need for unsubscribing.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the proper support for viewChange is a TODO item in Angular Material code. Here is extract from the latest version as of today.

```ts
// TODO(andrewseguin): Remove max value as the end index
//   and instead calculate the view on init and scroll.
/**
 * Stream containing the latest information on what rows are being displayed on screen.
 * Can be used by the data source to as a heuristic of what data should be provided.
 */
viewChange: BehaviorSubject<{start: number, end: number}> =
    new BehaviorSubject<{start: number, end: number}>({start: 0, end: Number.MAX_VALUE});
```

And it is never used in the component.