# How to get the data which is shown only in the page of material datatable with pagination

Tags: angular, datatable, pagination, angular-material, angular6

I need to export data which is displayed currently on the page to excel or pdf.
So how could I get the data which is only displayed on the page. I am storing the whole data in datasource object. 
eg:- If items per page is 10 , I need the 10 items. If I change the paginator Item list to 20 ,then I need the 20 Items.

Component HTML

```
   <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8 mat_datatable" matSort matSortActive="total_click" matSortDirection="desc" multiTemplateDataRows matSortDisableClear>
```

component.ts

```
   import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from 
  '@angular/material';

   this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reports);
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
   this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

This is my component files.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is the problem?

Comment: I need to export data which is displayed currently on the page to excel or pdf. How can I get the datatable displayed data.

Comment: actual data sits beside `this.reports`.

Comment: @NasiruddinSaiyed - I dont need the whole data. I need the data which is shown on the page. If items per page is 10 , I need the 10 items. If I change the paginator Item list to 20 ,then I need the 20 Items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use below code to skip few records and filter or take the current page records:

```
const skip = this.paginator.pageSize * this.paginator.pageIndex;

const pagedData = this.data.filter((u, i) => i >= skip)
   .filter((u, i) => i <this.paginator.pageSize);
```

Created a working demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n9yojx

Answer (score 14):

@User3250 's answer is good if you do not sort and filter your data. If your data is sorted or filtered, it will still extract the elements that would appear if it was not.

```
this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData, this.dataSource.sort).filter((u, i) => i >= skip)
    .filter((u: AlerteRow, i: number) => i < this.paginator.pageSize);
```

will make it work in all cases